# Pandas bar plot always creates an empty subplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, subplot

I want to plot two bar plots in one figure, but I always fail.

Below is my code:

```
def plot_data_group2(factor,xlabel): #xlabel: 这里是为了x轴坐标设置的
    survived_count=survived_passenger.groupby([factor])['PassengerId'].count()    
    fig_1 = plt.figure() #指定figure的宽和高，单位为英寸
    fig_1=plt.subplot(121)
    survived_count.plot(kind='bar')
    fig_1.set_title('Survived rate group by ' + factor)
    fig_1.set_xlabel(factor)
    fig_1.set_ylabel("count of the survived")
    plt.xticks(rotation=0) #旋转x轴的标签至水平（默认是和x轴垂直的）    
    fig_2=plt.subplot(122)
    survived_count_group = titanic_data.groupby([factor, 'Survived'])['PassengerId'].count().unstack()
    survived_rate = survived_count_group.apply(lambda x: (x / x.sum() * 100),axis=1)
    survived_rate.plot(kind='bar')
    fig_2.set_title('Survived rate group by ' + factor)
    fig_2.set_xlabel(factor)
    fig_2.set_ylabel("ration of " + factor + " in the survived")
    plt.xticks(rotation=0)    
    #plt.show()
plot_data_group2('Age_group',['under 18','young','not old','old'])
```

The output is the following:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

Change `survived_rate.plot(kind='bar')` to `survived_rate.plot(kind='bar', ax=fig_2)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why pandas DataFrame.plot isn't working exactly the same as plotting the data using pyplot.plot.

However, you can pass axes explicitly to DataFrame.plot with keyword arguments. See if this example makes any sense.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# random test data
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
y = x ** 2
# data in a pandas frame with 2 columns
df = pd.DataFrame([x, y]).T

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2) # (n rows, n cols)
df.plot(0, 1, ax=ax[0])
df.plot(0, 1, ax=ax[1])
plt.show()
```